# php backward function - calculate crude value

Tags: php, function

I have 13 functions for calculating some parameters. I stored calculated data at database. Now I need crude values. 
For example

```
function calculatex($value){
return $value*2; }
 echo calculatex(4); 
//will print 8
```

is there a way like

```
echo un-calculatex(8);
// will print 4
```

ps: all functions have only one parameter.

Comment: Just write an additional function that does the inverse of whatever `calculate` does.  In your example, it would simply `return $value / 2;`, no?

Comment: Functions are too long so it will have a lot of time to write inverse of them.

Answer (score 1):

It totally depends on what happens inside the original functions.

For a simple calculation like the example in your question, it's possible to write an inverse function for it to determine the input that produced a given output. For your example, just dividing should work reliably:

```
function un_calculatex($value) {
    return $value / 2;
}
echo un_calculatex(8);  // 4
```

But you will only be able to do this if the original function produces exactly one unique output for each input. It's very easy to write a function that doesn't do this, and if any of your functions are like that, there's really no way to reliably get back to the original input. A couple of simple examples:

```
function example1($a) {
    return ($a < 5) ? ($a * 2) : $a;
}
echo example1(3);  // 6
echo example1(6);  // 6

function example2($b) {
    return $b * $b;
}
echo example2(2);  // 4
echo example2(-2); // 4

function example3($c) {
    return (time() % 5) + $c;
}
echo example3(42); // who knows
```

You'll have to review each of your original functions to determine whether it's possible.

Comment: Thanks. No one of functions have if condition or multiply negative numbers, or pruduce value with time. All of my functions make basic math operations. Functions are too long so it will have a lot of time to write inverse of them.

Comment: @sipdorus You're welcome! I hope it works out. Just be cautious, those are just a few examples, but there are a lot of different ways a function can be made non-invertible or non-deterministic, and it may not be that obvious.